# Asp.net - Display hide table onclick Page_PreRender function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, html-table

I want to display/hide a table (Asp.net application) based on user click.

I have used the following code at Page_PreRender function, it is working fine in IE, but not in Firefox and chrome. The problem here is no changes are happening when I click on Chrome or Firefox.

```
    ColourKey.Attributes.Add("rules","all");
    ColourKey.Style.Add("border-collapse","collapse");
    ColourKey.Rows[0].Style.Add("cursor","hand");
    ColourKey.Rows[0].Attributes.Add("onClick",
        "var Display=this.parentElement.rows(2).style.display==''?'none':'';"
        +"for(var Count=1;Count<this.parentElement.rows.length;Count++) "
        +"this.parentElement.rows(Count).style.display=Display;");
```

Any idea?

Comment: Hello, would you like to try jquery hide function?? it's much easier, you just need to set a function that would hide the table then call the function in the "OnClientClick" event of the button

Comment: why don't you do the same in JQuery or Javascript?

Comment: I am adding the rows from code behind by exploring db, so my previous developer had done in this way. Is it not a proper way?

Comment: Just to hide the a table going to code behind is not a good practice.

Comment: Ok. But, why is ik working in IE not in Firefox?

Comment: There will be many reasons. possibly parser in web browsers